# Swift SpriteKit creating mutable path (CGMutablePathRef)

Tags: swift, path, sprite-kit, mutable

I found this code on stack overflow.

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, -(self.tileSize.height / 2))
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, (self.tileSize.width / 2), 0)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, (self.tileSize.height / 2))
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -(self.tileSize.width / 2), 0)
CGPathCloseSubpath(path)
```

its a part of an answer and the code should create a path that have the shape of an isometric tile but its not working. So somebody knows why and how to create this mutablePath?
Thank you.

Comment: Please define `"but its not working"`. What is your expected outcome and what is happening instead? Finally this is Objective-C code, not Swift.

Comment: at the first line: "CGMutablePathRef = pathCGPathCreateMutable()" i get an error: "use of unresolved Identifier "pathCGPathCreateMutable".. something is wrong with this code. I want to give it a size and i get back a opaque path i can use. if i click inside that path something happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is that the code does not compile, you just need to convert it from Objective-C to Swift

```
let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, -(self.tileSize.height / 2))
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, (self.tileSize.width / 2), 0)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, (self.tileSize.height / 2))
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, -(self.tileSize.width / 2), 0)
CGPathCloseSubpath(path)
```